# How install MySQL 5.1 in Ubuntu 12.04 server from repository

Tags: mysql, installation, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-server, mysql-5.1

I need to install MySQL 5.1 in Ubuntu Server. I have seen in other question to use 
 *deb http://packages.dotdeb.org lenny all* 
but it is not working. Are there any other repository??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about installing software.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

cd ~/
wget http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/mysql-5.1/mysql-5.1.65.tar.gz
tar -zxf mysql-5.1.65.tar.gz
cd mysql-5.1.65
./configure  '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--libexecdir=/usr/sbin' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--localstatedir=/var/lib/mysql' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--with-system-type=debian-linux-gnu' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--enable-thread-safe-client' '--enable-assembler' '--enable-local-infile' '--with-fast-mutexes' '--with-big-tables' '--with-unix-socket-path=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' '--with-mysqld-user=mysql' '--with-libwrap' '--without-readline' '--with-ssl' '--without-docs' '--with-extra-charsets=all' '--with-plugins=max' '--with-embedded-server' '--with-embedded-privilege-control'
make
sudo make install
```